# mysql should i use apostrophe in mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, coding-style, standards

What is the correct way of writing a query to a MySQL database on numeric data-types:

```
  SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = 5;
```

or

```
  SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = '5';
```

Mainly I prefer the last one, using `'` because it is more consistent with text data-types.

Does it effect the performance?

Comment: `because it is more consistent with text datatypes` - but it's not a text datatype.

Comment: Type mismatch in a query may result in a full table scan - see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11623/mysql-text-field-without-quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes are for strings, MySQL is going to read those quotes and then cast it to an integer, this is slower then just handing it an int to begin with.

Honestly the performance difference is minor, but it is just like writing a program that stores numbers in strings and then casts to int when it needs to do some math. This is bad practice.

Comment: The implicit type cast that goes with "numbers as strings" can also have potentially un-wanted side effects (such as triggers not being used)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that you can measure any noticable difference between the speed of the two queries. If you care about the performance you should ensure that you have an index on the `id` column. If you do, both queries will be very fast.

However there are security considerations.

**The official MySQL opinion**

The [MySQL client security guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/secure-client-programming.html) recommend that you do use quotes.

> A common mistake is to protect only string data values. Remember to check numeric data as well. If an application generates a query such as SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=234 when a user enters the value 234, the user can enter the value `234 OR 1=1` to cause the application to generate the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=234 OR 1=1`. As a result, the server retrieves every row in the table. This exposes every row and causes excessive server load. **The simplest way to protect from this type of attack is to use single quotation marks around the numeric constants: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='234'`**.

Emphasis mine.

**My opinion**

Although the documentation recommends the use of quotes, it is neither *necessary* nor *sufficient* to prevent the attack it describes. For example, changing the attacker's string to `234' OR '1'='1` would defeat their approach.

In my opinion, a better way to make your application secure is to use **parameterized queries** instead of putting user values directly into the string.

If for some reason you can't use parameterized queries, then don't use quotes but ensure that the variable does in fact contain an integer by using the [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function.

Comment: I didn't know they actually promote such a bad behaviour. Recommending to write number literals as string literals fits into the overal picture I have of MySQL.

Comment: did not know this either... some time ago I had problems with performance when using quotes around numeric values...

Comment: This is still not best practice, a simple way to protect int input is to just cast it as int... eg `$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . (int)$id;`. If its already an integer, the cast has no effect and no slowdown, if it isn't a valid int, it will return 0, or in the MySQL example just the number 1.

Comment: When doing the implicit type cast the other way round (using numbers against character columns), things get even more confusing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fda45/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - You should never cast that way around, it will be text data and it will be enclosed in quotes, otherwise MySQL will be casting int to string.

Comment: parameterized queries is definitely the way to go, never put user input directly into your SQL query string

Comment: @Geoffrey: that's what I wanted to point out: relying on *any* implicit type casting is a bad idea. The "syntax" of the literals should match the datatype of the column.

Comment: Great idea, now all the user has to do is to add a few single quotes to his input; `234' OR '1'='1`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of the id you can use either '5' or 5. Usually id is the primary key and is of type int so you should use 5

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes, when the field type in your database is a string. Otherwise, if it is numeric, do not use quotes. If you use quotes for a numeric field type it can really slow down queries, because mysql has to match strings to numbers.

Comment: had this problem too, when using quotes for numeric values!

Answer (score 1):

Using a quoted number against a column whose type is defined to be numeric has a *teeny* performance hit as compared to using an unquoted value, as the server has to convert the string to the right type during query compilation. Other than that it has no effect, and you probably will be hard pressed to measure the hit at all. (Note that as both "0" and 0 are sent to the server as strings they have to be converted to the internal type of the field before use anyway, as such sending "0" merely forces an extra step. First the parser parses out the "0" then the optimizer notices the column type is numeric and converts it accordingly. OTOH, with 0 the parser will parse it as a numeric [storing as an long int iirc], then notice the type of the field, and convert the numeric to the appropriate field type if necessary. So the difference really is insignificant).

However, using an *unquoted* number against a column whose type is defined to be *text* is a very very bad idea, as it means that server cannot use any index on the column to resolve the query.

It is important to understand that while any given string nummifies to exactly one numeric value there are a nearly infinite set of strings which nummify to a given numeric value. Consider "0", "0E0", "0.0" etc. This explains why quoting the constraint when the field is numeric is not really bad, there is only operation to perform, and it explains why NOT quoting the constraint *is* bad when the field is not numeric, as it means the server has to cast each string in the table to a number before doing the comparison, thus forcing a table scan.